# React component not rendering to rails view (root)

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My aim is to load airlines.js for the view root, so essentially I should see 'This is the airlines#index view for our app', however at the moment it's a blank page. What am I doing wrong here? When I console.log in the
document.addEventListener('DOMcontentLoaded' nothing is showing up.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Airlines from './Airlines'
import Airline from './Airline'

const App = () => {
    return (
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Airlines}/>
        <Route exact path="/airlines/:slug" component={Airline}/>
    </Routes>
    )
}
```

Airline.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Airline = () => {
    return <div>This is the airline#show view for our app</div>
}

export default Airline



export default App
```

Airlines.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Airlines = () => {
    const [airlines, setAirlines] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/api/v1/airlines.json')
        .then(resp => console.log(resp))
        .catch(resp => console.log(resp))
    }, [airlines.length])

    return <div>This is the airlines#index view for our app</div>
}

export default Airlines
```

APP.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Airlines from './Airlines'
import Airline from './Airline'

    const App = () => {
        return (
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Airlines}/>
            <Route exact path="/airlines/:slug" component={Airline}/>
        </Routes>
        )
    }
    
    export default App
```

index.jsx

```
// import Welcome from './components/Welcome'
import App from './components/App'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

document.addEventListener('DOMcontentLoaded', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router>
            <Route path='/' component={App}/>
        </Router>,
        document.body.appendChild(document.getElementById('welcome'))
    )
})
```